# allow gripper collision on the PR-2

Tags: ros, collision, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to allow the PR-2 gripper to collide with objects on a table.  I am designing linear pushing motions.  I am using motion_planning_msgs/CollisionOperation message in the MoveArmGoal message, but it does not seem to work.

Here are the message definitions.  I use their example of object1 = "gripper" and object2 = COLLISION_SET_ALL.  Any suggestion will be very helpful!

```
# A definition of a collision operation
# E.g. ("gripper",COLLISION_SET_ALL,ENABLE) will enable collisions 
# between the gripper and all objects in the collision space

string object1
string object2
string COLLISION_SET_ALL="all"
string COLLISION_SET_OBJECTS="objects"
string COLLISION_SET_ATTACHED_OBJECTS="attached"

# The penetration distance to which collisions are allowed. This is 0.0 by default.
float64 penetration_distance

# Flag that determines whether collisions will be enabled or disabled for the pair of objects specified above
int32 operation
int32 DISABLE=0
int32 ENABLE=1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9617/allow-gripper-collision-on-the-pr-2/) by [guzza](https://answers.ros.org/users/374/guzza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guzza,

If i remember well, for the pick action, the motion to the pre-grasp is planified with collision detection. But the last trajectory segment, from pre-grasp to grasp position, is made without collision detection.

I would suggest you to adopt the same approach: go to a pre-push position with a collision aware method and then switch to a non-collision-aware movement.

For how to do this last operation you can take a look at [this tutorial.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20through%20a%20Cartesian%20pose%20trajectory)

Hope this helps,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1